# I think these groups don't exist

Tags: group-theory

A group $G$ is said to be decomposable if $G= A \times B$ (direct product). I am looking for an example of an indecomposable group (non-abelian) with a very large centre relative to the order of the group. Are there groups (non-abelian) $G$ such that $G$ is indecomposable and $Z(G) = c|G|$ where $c$ is very small relative to $|G|$?

Comment: What is $c$ here? Obviously it cannot be greater then $1$. On the other hand if it is arbitrary then this is trivially true: every group has such constant, namely $|Z(G)|/|G|$.

Comment: Like $1/|G|$? Every simple group has trivial center and is indecomposable. You can't have smaller center.

Comment: @ freakish  but i want the opposite, group with very large center and indecomposable

Comment: So you meant $c$ as big as possible in $(0,1)$ range.

Comment: @ freakish  yes. or in other words a indecomposable group with largest possible center.

Comment: So how big do you want it to be (note that $c<1/2$ for sure)? You have to put some additional assumptions on $c$. As it is the statement is trivially satisfied by any group.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is well-known that $G/Z(G)$ cannot be nontrivial and    cyclic, so we must have $|G/Z(G)| \ge 4$.

For all $n\ge 2$, the group of order $2^{n+1}$ defined by the presentation
$$\langle x,y \mid x^{2^n}=y^2=1,y^{-1}xy=x^{2^{n-1}+1} \rangle$$
has centre $\langle x^2 \rangle$ of index $4$, and it is easily shown to be indecomposable. So there are arbitrarily large finite groups with $|G/Z(G)|=4$.

These groups are sometimes called *modular groups*. They are one of the four families of nonabelian $2$-groups that have a maximal cyclic subgroup, which are discussed [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quasidihedral_group).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Please name the group you have given above in the answer. Are there well known groups which satisfy requirements I have mentioned in my question?

Comment: See my edit. I think you could get further examples by allowing $y$ to have order a larger power of $2$, but apart from that I do not know of any other indecomposable groups with $|G/Z(G)|=4$.